# How to stop a function in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How i can stop a function in another function?

For example:

```js
var snow = function(){
  var interval = setInterval( function(){
    alert('letItSnow')
  }, 1000);
};
snow();
```

clearInterval(snow.interval) -  exception

Comment: Your `clearInterval` throws an exception because the variables in a function are not properties on the Function object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, access scopes are limited via function declarations, so your locally declared variables won't be accessible outside, hence you must return it or set it to a global variable (variable available in parent scope)

you need to make a slight adjustment to your function, do it like this:

```
var snow = function(){
            return setInterval(function(){
                alert('letItSnow');
            }, 1000);

        };

   var interval = snow();
   //on some event -- clearInterval(interval)
```

you can also make the `setTimeout` and its returned id a property to the `function` which would be available on all of its instances i.e.

```
var snowClass = function(){
     this.init = function(msg){
        this.interval = setInterval(function(){alert(msg)},1000);
    }

}
var snowObj  = new snowClass();
snowObj.init('Let it snow');
//on some event -- clearInterval(snowObj.interval)
```

Answer (score 1):

you referring to `snow.interval` which assumed to be property of `snow` object. but in your code `interval` is just local variable. instead you might want to define `interval` in the global scope so it will be accessible globally http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

```
var interval, snow = function(){
  interval = setInterval( function(){
    console.log('letItSnow')
  }, 1000);
};
snow();
clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to stop the interval outside of the `snow` function.

You can declare the `interval` variable outside of the `snow` function in order to use it (to clear the interval) outside of the `snow` function.

```js
var interval;
var snow = function(){
    interval = setInterval(
        function(){
            alert('letItSnow')
        },
        1000
    );
};
snow();
clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your code

```js
var timeout1 = {};
var timeout2 = {};

function function1(){
//codes
   if(timeout2){
      clearTimeout(timeout2);
   }
   timeout1 = setTimeout("function1()",5000);
}    

function function2(){
//codes
   if(timeout1){
       clearTimeout(timeout1);
   }
   timeout2 = setTimeout("function2()",5000);
}
```